# Can American Option Be Exercised After It's Not ITM Anymore

Tags: options, option-exercise

If an (American style) option enters the in-the-money price zone on a day while the person holding the options contract isn't paying attention to the market, and later on (let's say the next day), the option price goes back to be out of the money, can the person holding the option exercise it on the next days (before it expires, of course)?

Comment: Why would he ever want to do this?? It’s burning good money.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

Sure - but that means that the holder of a call option is buying the stock for more than they could on the open market (or sell for less if they exercise a put), so it's a bad deal for the holder to exercise an OTM option.

Note that it's *almost always* better to sell an option to close it out rather then exercise early, whether it's ITM or not. You'll get more for the option that you would make by exercising it.

Comment: Thank you for the insight

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any OCC rule that says that out-of-the-money American options cannot be exercised.  However, some brokers do not allow it - perhaps a customer protective feature.  It is possible that such an option could be exercised if it was briefly in-the-money during the day, ending the day out-of-the-money.

It makes no sense to exercise an option if it has remaining time premium because doing so throws away that time premium (a time premium of something more than a couple of cents).

It does make sense to exercise a deep ITM option if it trades below parity (the bid is less than the intrinsic value) and you can't get fair value for it.  In such case, you'd take an opposing position in the underlying in order to maximize the return.

Comment: well explained. Thanks